# Is it possible to use the same view for two diffrent actions?

Tags: fluid, typo3-flow

i am trying to share one view with two actions from the same controller and i am quite struggling. Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result? Please include the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Fluid expects a template in Resources/Private/Templates/ControllerName/ActionName.html

So each action expects its own template. If I understand you correctly, you want two different ations to use the same Fluid-Template. You can achieve this in two different ways:

#### 1. Use Partials:

Just put your hole Fluid-Template of action A to a partial and render that partial in the template for acion A and action B with:

```
<f:render partial="YourPartial" />
```

So you have two templates, but both are rendering the same partial.

---

#### 2. Set the template for action B to be the template of action A:

You can overwrite the default template of an action with:

```
$this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePathAndFilename);
```

You need to give the full path to a template file. Then Fluid will use this template instead of the default one.

*Note: The 2nd suggestion is woking in TYPO3 CMS, but since extbase is backportet from flow, it should be possible to do this in flow as well.*

Comment: Second solution works for Flow framework 3.0 `$this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename('resource://My.Package/Private/Templates/MyController/Index.html');`